# SQL query in Apps Script (to combine multiple google sheets into one)

Tags: javascript

I am using this apps script to combine multiple gsheets into 1.

```
  function Import_Data_From_Multi_Sources(){
  
// Input  
var spreadsheetId='19hT5qOy-1y-29DutFIGA1mIKC1ZWm4rLe19mvHpHN1Y' // current sheet id
var destination_range= "tiering_B22_master!A2:W"
var sources = [
    {source_fileID: '1xAsqdozO-2GqP8JEX2nwfZbWslSmL8NMhzbiGaZ19PM', source_sheetName: "Contact Leads",source_range:"A2:AN", source_select_columns: [1,4,6,11,12,18,19,21,22,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]},
    {source_fileID: '1txFgswaIINK60-K5lyC6W6_JnFAV8gJBj1HT80fc-fg', source_sheetName: "Contact Leads",source_range:"A2:AN", source_select_columns: [1,4,6,11,12,18,19,21,22,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]},
    {source_fileID: '1xAsqdozO-2GqP8JEX2nwfZbWslSmL8NMhzbiGaZ19PM', source_sheetName: "LZD template new",source_range:"A2:AN", source_select_columns: [1,4,6,11,12,18,19,21,22,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]}
    ]


var combine_data=[]
for (x in sources){
  try{
  var s_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sources[x].source_fileID)
  var s_sheet = s_file.getSheetByName(sources[x].source_sheetName)
  var s_selRange = s_sheet.getRange(sources[x].source_range);
  var s_selCol = sources[x].source_select_columns;
  var s_selValue = s_selRange.getDisplayValues();
  //filter skip blank rows
  s_selValue = s_selValue.filter(function (xRow) {return xRow.join('').length >0});

  var s_values= [];
    for (let i = 0, length = s_selValue.length; i < length; i++) {
      s_values[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0, width  = s_selCol.length; j < width; j++) {
        // assign source value to a variable
            let col_value = s_selValue[i][s_selCol[j]-1];
            let actual_col = s_selCol[j];

// format phone value before copying
            let phone_cols = [6, 11];
            if ( phone_cols.includes(actual_col) ) {
col_value = col_value.trim();
           }
            s_values[i][j] = col_value;
      };
    };
}catch (error) {
    var mess ='\nURL: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() +  '\nSheet '+sources[x].source_sheetName + ' Range ' + sources[x].source_range + ' ' + error
    console.log(mess)
    var subject = 'Errors' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();//Change to subject
    var emailUser = 'minh.le.nhat@shopee.com';//Change to email you want to send to
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailUser,subject,mess)
    continue}
  combine_data=combine_data.concat(s_values);
  //console.log(combine_data)

}

  
  var data = 
  {
    'range':destination_range,
    'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'values':combine_data
  }
  var clearRange=
  {
    "ranges":destination_range
  }


var update = {
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    data: data
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchClear(clearRange, spreadsheetId);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(update, spreadsheetId);
}
```

As you can see this script is used to combine and select certain columns from the source data that I want to combine

I wonder if anyone can help me to modify this code so that I can write SQL statement in this script to get data with conditions that I want.
I mean now the code will get columns with all data from that column, but what if i only want to get conditions like where and so on. So I would love to write SQL to get data before I can combine them. I know there is a work around way that uses query in the source URL before running this script but I want to write SQL statement directly in this script

I tried very hard to look up on Google but no one gives me an answer

Love to see any reply and help

Best